# spatie / laravel-permission can return always true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

when using laravel spatie permissions every thing is ok when creating permissions , roles , assign roles to users.
but when using `$this->authorize('View Country')` OR `$user->can('View Country')` always return `true`.
i am using laravel **v9.0** and spatie/permissions **v5.5**
and tried some solutions like :

- upgrade spatie/permissions to **v6.0**
- running `php artisan optimize`

but noting happen

**assign role to user:**

```
$user = Admin::findOrFail(request('user_id'));
        $role = Role::findOrFail(request('role_id'));
        $user->syncRoles([$role->name]);
        return redirect()->route('admin.admins.index')->with('success', __(" Successfully"));
```

---

**create role permissions and sync**

```
$role = Role::find(request('role_id', 1));
        foreach ($request->permissions as $permisssion) {
            $permisssions[] = Permission::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => $permisssion,
                'guard_name' => 'admin'
            ]);
        }
        $role->syncPermissions($permisssions ?? []);
```

Comment: show database data and how you assign the roles etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to:

- check defined permissions with `php artisan permission:show`
- check users permisions using `php artisan tinker`and entering a commanad like: `User::where('id', '<', 11)->get()->map(fn ($user) => [[$user->id, $user->name], $user->getAllPermissions()->pluck ('name')->toArray()])` (customize the *where condition* as your needings)
- check if you have defined a *Custom Permission*, finding in your code *'Gate::before'* (tipically is set in *boot* method of *app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php*) - look [here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/advanced-usage/custom-permission-check) and [here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/super-admin) for reference

Comment: the last point solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

It's usually cache issue in the package. Try clearing cache (`php artisan cache:clear`) and let the package handle the caching.

Comment: nothing happen same problem

Answer (score 0):

Pode limpar o cache utilizando o comando:

```
 app()->make(\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class)->forgetCachedPermissions();
app()->make(\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class)->clearClassPermissions();
           app()->make(\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class)->registerPermissions();
```

Para criar e vincular as permissões:

```
  foreach ($permissoes as $permissao) {
            $permission = Permission::create($permissao);
            $role->givePermissionTo($permission);
        }
```

No model User deve chamar

```
 use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
class Usuario extends  Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;
```

Pode verificar a permissão do usuário com:

```
auth()->user()->can('View Country')
```